# UI-bootstrap typeahead does not resolve promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

## Problem description

Hi, I have a problem with UI-Bootstrap's typeahead, there is standard example on the homepage that demonstrates typeahead usage:

http://plnkr.co/edit/LS5OMsnQtdsJ87eW4pjG?p=preview

This example works pretty fine until I start using promises with `typeahead` directive:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZuUBDOPcOJIW0Bkskrb5?p=preview

The change is pretty simple, I've replaced direct variable initialisation with delayed initialisation using $timeout service, as a result typeahead stops working

## Question:

What am I doing wrong? It is clearly stated that UI-Bootstrap's typeahead: `works with promises and it means that you can retrieve matches using the $http service with minimal effort`

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be returning a promise that resolves to matched results:

```
$scope.getStates = function($viewValue) {    
    return $timeout(function () {
      return filterFilter(['Alabama', 'Alaska', ...], $viewValue);
    }, 1000);    
  };
```

and then in HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in getStates($viewValue)">
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/RAkzX0UoWHVLUOZ6jEyA?p=preview

The way you've written your expression in a promise being filtered.

Comment: Good info, and this resolved my problem as well, but it seems to be totally counter to what the ui bootstrap documentation says.