# How to correctly resolve a javascript promise for a bs-typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, grafana

I'm working on a project to develop a [datasource plugin for Grafana](https://github.com/jameskirsop/grafana-healthchecksio-datasource). This means that I'm stuck with what appears to be reasonably old versions of some of the AngularJS libraries/modules. The Grafana project also [seems to have pulled out the use of `$q`](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/commit/880fbcb09a5ab1a63f69811db8a94ba76ac7bf0f#diff-91c7dfd6b6f227683b0008a523a0bfb8), and as a result I'm trying to work out how to use native Promise objects where possible (Promises are also something I'm new to).

I've got a [bs-typeahead form input](https://github.com/jameskirsop/grafana-healthchecksio-datasource/blob/0c41902ed81eae5711802012caedd8d37effe0a4/src/partials/query.editor.html#L17) which is correctly calling the following promise which returns results:

```
getOptions(query) {
  console.log('Getting options')
  return this.datasource.metricFindQuery(query || '').then(a => {
    console.log(a);
    this.scope.$digest();
    return a
  });
}
```

However, the bs-typeahead drop down doesn't appear showing the results, despite an array showing the expected results being logged to the console.

With `this.scope.$digest();` in the function, I get an error of `$digest already in progress`, and so now I'm stuck with where/how I should be calling $scope.$digest(), or if that's the best approach. If I remove that line I don't get an error, but no results appear.

I've taken a look at a [few](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/promises-angular-q#es2015-promises) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897002/ui-bootstrap-typeahead-does-not-resolve-promise) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427141/bootstrap-typeahead-not-populating-with-response-from-promise) to try and get this to work, but haven't had any success thus far.

If I swap out the getOptions `return` for a plain array (eg. `['a','b','c']`) the lookahead works without any issue - so I'm confident the issue is with the Promise.

It seems like `$scope.$apply`, [could be an option](https://medium.com/@TuiZ/digest-already-in-progress-c0f97a6becfc), but again I'm not sure where it should sit in the context of the codebase.

What should I be doing to get the promise to resolve appropriately in light of the bs-typeahead?

The whole Javascript file that the above function resides in is available [here](https://github.com/jameskirsop/grafana-healthchecksio-datasource/blob/0c41902ed81eae5711802012caedd8d37effe0a4/src/query_ctrl.js#L52).

Beyond assistance with my immediate question, an explanation of how the Promise(s) resolve in my particular context would be a great help in making sure I'm understanding the concept correctly.

Comment: If `getOptions()` works when it returns Array but not when it returns Promise, then the caller is not expecting Promise. In all probabilty, you need to modify the caller.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your typeahead is not able to handle a Promise.

You will have to manually provided an Array and update it once the Promise is resolved.

```js
getOptions(query) {
  let result = [];
  console.log('Getting options')
  this.datasource.metricFindQuery(query || '').then(a => {
    console.log(a)
    a.forEach(item => result.push(item));
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, presumably for the same reasons I linked to in my post (also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427141/bootstrap-typeahead-not-populating-with-response-from-promise).
If I console.log() the result var before returning, it gets printed to the console *before* the console.log() of the then() promise (see http://dpaste.com/1WRBVQY), so the promise doesn't appear to be resolving before the function returns.

Comment: The `console.log` are normal since the then is called asynchronously. Except that the `result` array will be updated once the promise is resolved. Moreover, according to the documentation (https://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads), you should  set the attribute "watchOptions" at true